# Google Earth Engine: Prevent Cloud mask algorithm for Landsat-8 from masking coastline

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, masking, cloud-cover

I am trying to remove clouds on Landsat image using cloud mask. However, the cloud mask removes even the shoreline that do not have clouds. I don't know why. Is there another way?
(upper: pre-masked image; lower: cloud masked image)

[image: original image]
[image: masked image]

The code to generate this images is below:

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([121.91094599921439, 36.819887452954504]);

var cloud_masks = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks');
var landsatSRfunction = cloud_masks.landsatSR;

// The original Image
var L8Image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterBounds(point)
  .filterDate('2014-04-01', '2014-05-30')
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
  .first();

// Apply mask
var masked_image = landsatSRfunction()(L8Image);

// Visualize
var vis = {bands:['B5', 'B7', 'B4'], min:0, max:5000}
Map.addLayer(L8Image, vis, 'origin');
Map.addLayer(masked_image, vis, 'Landsat 8 SR masked');
Map.centerObject(masked_image, 10)
```

Comment: Did you try cloud score? QA band sadly removes some areas without clouds, like snow and shorelines